# Devise sign_out not working in test - can still access after sign_out, no redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

This is my controller with devise:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:mypage]
```

and route:

```
  get "/mypage", to: "users#mypage"
```

Now I want to test sign-in and sign-out. My test is:

```
class RorIntegrationTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers

  test "sign_in then sign_out" do
    get "/mypage"
    user = users(:someuser)
    assert_response :redirect

    sign_in(user)
    get "/mypage"
    assert_response :success

    sign_out(user)
    get "/mypage"
    assert_response :redirect # this is line 17
  end
```

but the result is:

```
Failure:
RorIntegrationTest#test_sign_in_then_sign_out [/ror/test/integration/ror_integration_test.rb:17]:
Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>

bin/rails test test/integration/ror_integration_test.rb:6
```

It seems that the first `get "/mypage"` is correctly redirected, but why is the second not redirected after `sign_out`?

Comment: What is your sign_out method? Could you show the code?

Comment: @Jeremie They're devise official, from `Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers`.

Comment: put "binding.pry", and check "controller.send(:current_user)" if it's present. Maybe session needs to be cleared. Check also test.log

Comment: Sorry, I'm back. Can we try something if you have done so before. Can you remove the line 15 to 17 and see if the test passes?